# Key violation when running append query the 1st time, but NOT the 2nd time

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, primary-key, ms-access-2013

I am getting an error that says that there is a key violation when I run an append query using VBA. However, I'm not doing anything to change the primary key of the table so why would there be a key violation?

Here's the strange part - the first time I run the append query, I get this key violation error. But when I run it again immediately, i.e. without doing ANYTHING ELSE, it works fine.

**The SQL string:**

```
INSERT INTO tblQuoteVendors (QuoteID, CompanyID, ContactID)
VALUES (360, 236, 491);
```

**Table Schema:**

```
Field Name    Datatype
ID            Autonumber
QuoteID       Number
CompanyID     Number
ContactID     Number
VendorQuote   Short Text
```

**Table relationships:**

#### Screenshot of table relationships

[image: Screenshot of table relationships]

Comment: Please provide a list of all indexes. Is `ID` the only indexed field? Are there any relationships that enforce referential integrity?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth all fields except VendorQuote are indexed. Yes, this table is related to other tables. I will add a screenshot of the relationships.

Comment: Have you checked all foreign keys and are they valid?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to your "doubled" relation between tblQuote and tblCompany here:

tblQuote.CompanyID/tblCompany.CompanyID

and here:

tlQuote.QuoteID/tblQuoteVendors.QuoteID - tblQuoteVendors.Company.ID/tblCompany.CompanyID

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same situation:

> Here's the strange part - the first time I run the append query, I get
>   this key violation error. But when I run it again immediately, i.e.
>   without doing ANYTHING ELSE, it works fine.

Compacting and repairing the DB solved the issue.